# How to interactively draw a bitmap with mouse?

Tags: dynamic, image

I cannot find the `MNIST` dynamic activation example I strongly believe I have seen in the documentation.

What would be the most efficient way to

1. draw a black & white bitmap interactively
2. have each edit evaluate a function (/ dynamic value)

?

---

There was a much more robust version of the below somewhere in the documentation I believe:

```
c // ClearAll
c[m_] := With[{w = Clip[m, {1, s}]}, a[[s - w[[2]], w[[1]]]] = 0];
a = ConstantArray[1, {s, s}];
DynamicModule[{},
  EventHandler[Dynamic@Image[a], {
    "MouseDragged" :> (c@MousePosition["Graphics"])
    }]
  ]
```

Comment: Open “Paint” or equivalent.  Or open the [drawing tools](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html).

Comment: @JasonB. - I need immediate programmatic access to what is being painted. See my edit.

Comment: @JasonB and Cetin: Check out "Neat examples" on the `Classify` documentation page. The very last one seems like what you want. Unfortunately, the raw code wasn't included and would be some trouble to retrieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Szabolcs' reference: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify#1782628206

```
s = 64;
a = ConstantArray[1, {s, s}];
DynamicModule[{p1, p2},
 Grid[{
   {
    EventHandler[Dynamic[Image[a], TrackedSymbols :> {a}], {
      "MouseDown" :> (p1 = p2 = PixelPos[]; PaintDot[a, p1]),
      "MouseDragged" :> (p1 = p2; p2 = PixelPos[]; 
        PaintLine[a, p1, p2])
      }]
    },
   {Button["clear", a = ConstantArray[1, {s, s}]]}}
  , Frame -> True
  ]
 ]
```

where (need to be defined first; kindly extracted by Szabolcs from the above example):

````
PixelPos[] := 
 Replace[MousePosition["Graphics"], {{i_, j_} :> Round[{64 - j, i}], 
          _ :> None}]

Attributes[PaintDot] = {HoldFirst};
PaintDot[data_Symbol, p : {i1_, j1_}] := Block[{dim = Length[data]}, 
        Do[
   If[EuclideanDistance[N[{i, j}], N[p]] < 2.5, data[[i, j]] = 0.], 
          {i, Max[i1 - 3, 1], Min[i1 + 3, dim]}, {j, Max[j1 - 3, 1], 
    Min[j1 + 3, dim]}]]

Attributes[PaintLine] = {HoldFirst};
PaintLine[data_Symbol, {i1_, j1_}, 
        {i2_, j2_}] := Block[{dim, indices, ib, ie, jb, je}, 
        indices = InterpolatePoints[N[{i1, j1}], N[{i2, j2}], 2.5]; 
         {ib, ie} = Sort[{i1, i2}]; {jb, je} = 
   Sort[{j1, j2}]; {{ib, jb}, {ie, je}} = 
           Clip[{{ib, jb} - 3, {ie, je} + 3}, {1, Length[data]}]; 
         Quiet[
   Do[If[Min[(EuclideanDistance[N[{i, j}], #1] & ) /@ indices] < 
      2.5, 
               data[[i, j]] = 0.], {i, ib, ie}, {j, jb, je}]]; ]

InterpolatePoints[start$_, stop$_] := Module[{dist$, unit$}, 
        dist$ = N[EuclideanDistance[start$, stop$]]; 
  If[dist$ < 3, 
           Return[{start$, stop$}]
   ];
   unit$ = Normalize[stop$ - N[start$]];
    Append[stop$][Table[start$ + i*unit$, {i, 0, dist$, 3}]]
  ]

InterpolatePoints[p1_, p2_, r_] := 
 Module[{d, v}, d = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]; 
         If[d < 2*r, Return[{p1, p2}]]; v = Normalize[p2 - p1]; 
         Developer`ToPackedArray[
   Append[p2][Table[p1 + i*v, {i, 0., d, r}]], Real]]
```
````

Comment: No, they're not undocumented functions. They're defined within the `Initialization :>` option of that `DynamicModule`. You can try to extract them if you have the time and patience ... You can also try to write to Wolfram and request the code for that documentation example (I would do that).

Comment: [Here are the missing definitions](https://pastebin.com/eL02PRkm). Can you clean them up and add them to the answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for your effort in extracting them! I first thought *any* `DynamicModule` defined them during initialization. It was just the one from that example and you have extracted them - thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. Btw, a background can be added, e.g. `bg = Graphics[{Blue, Circle[{32, 32}, #] & /@ {9, 20, 30}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 64}, {0, 64}}, ImageSize -> 64]` by replacing `Image[a]` with `Show[Graphics[Inset[Image[a, ImageSize -> s]]], bg, PlotRange -> {{0, s}, {0, s}}, ImageSize -> s]`